# __TABLES__ gives incorrect results on table size

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have executed `SELECT * FROM [data_det_name.__TABLES__] where table_id = 'table_name'` which gives me both `row_count` and `size_bytes` as `0`.

But table has 3 records.
I have done this using both webui and python api.

Table `creation_time` and `last_modified_time`(inserted time) are `23 Sep 2016 05:05:40.832 GMT` and `23 Sep 2016 06:14:37.358 GMT` respectively. The above query executed time is, `23 Sep 2016 08:17:17 GMT`.

**N.B:**  It's `'cacheHit':False`.

---

**UPDATE** : Data correctly retrieved after few hours. Seems like the api or query ui wont give at least near real time data from that table. Any method that I can get the updated results soon?

Comment: silly guess: is `table_name` even present in `data_det_name`?

Comment: maybe it only has selected rows rather than all of them?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev yes its there and it shows the  `creation_time` and `last_modified_time`. __ TABLES __ gives the meta data of the table. For some of my tables it shows correctly.

Comment: ppl This is regarding bigquery python api which I want to get the storage_size of a table. This is not off topic.  Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266740/how-to-get-bigquery-storage-size-for-a-single-table

Comment: I voted this off-topic for lacking a [mcve]. Without it, there's not enough info to reproduce the problem or say what you're doing that might be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where table_id = 'table_name'
```

Comment: No this wont give the result. It fails