# How does Flyway estimate the 10GB data limit for its BigQuery extension?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, flyway, schema-migration

I am interested in [Flyway's BigQuery extension](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/big-query) and planning to use in an unfunded small project for **schema migration**.

However, I couldn't find any details in term of how the 10GB data limit is being calculated.

I have tried creating and updating a dataset using the extension but I am still seeing below in my app logs:

- You have used 0 GB / 10 GB

Anyone has the details of the calculation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The size is calculated using the query mentioned below but for all tables.
[How to get BigQuery storage size for a single table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266740/how-to-get-bigquery-storage-size-for-a-single-table)

Why do you need to know how flyway implements this?

Comment: Hi, it is because the project can't afford Flyway's enterprise license, if the 10GB quota can be hit very easily, then I shall seek for other solution.

Sorry, I have more questions about the calculation.

Let's say I have below tables:

Table A - 1GB
Table B - 500MB

Now, I do a migration that adds 1 new column in both tables.
How much data is considered used ? Is it 1.5GB ?

Is the data limit accumulative? Or is it a one off? For example, every execution will have 10GB ?