# With SQL or Python how can I find out if a table is part of a sharded set of tables (in BigQuery)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics

I want to find out what my table sizes are (in BigQuery).
However I want to sum up the size of of all tables that belong to a specific set of sharded tables.
So I need to find metadata that shows that a table is part of a set of sharded tables.

So I can do: [How to get BigQuery storage size for a single table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266740/how-to-get-bigquery-storage-size-for-a-single-table)

```sql
select 
  sum(size_bytes)/pow(2, 30) as size_gb
from
  <your_dataset>.__TABLES__
```

But here I can't see if the table is part of a set of sharded set of tables.

This is what my Google Analytics sharded tables look like in BQ:

[image: big query sharded tables representation]

So somewhere must be metadata that indicates that tables with for example name `ga_sessions_20220504` belong to a sharded set `ga_sesssions_`

Where/how can I find that metadata?

Comment: How do you identify your sharded tables? Is it something like [prefix]_YYYYMMDD?

Comment: @CarlosSR I added more info to the question :)

Comment: What about using <your_dataset>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS ?

Comment: Sharded tables are not partitions. They are a group of tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no metadata on Sharded tables via SQL.

Tables being displayed as Sharded in BigQuery UI happens when you do the following ->

Create 2 or more tables that have the following characteristics:

- exist in the same dataset
- have the exact same table schema
- the same prefix
- have a suffix of the form _YYYYMMDD (eg. 20210130)

These are something of a legacy feature, they were more commonly used with bigquery’s legacy SQL.

This blog was very insightful on this:
https://mark-mccracken.medium.com/bigquery-date-sharding-vs-date-partitioning-cee3754f7900

Answer (score 2):

I think you are exploring the right query, most of the time, I use the following query to drill down on shards & it's sizes

```
SELECT
  project_id,
  dataset_id,
  table_id,
  array_reverse(SPLIT(table_id, '_'))[OFFSET(0)] AS shard_pt,
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time)) creation_dt,
  ROUND(size_bytes/POW(1024, 3), 2) size_in_gb
FROM
  `<project>.<dataset>.__TABLES__`
WHERE
  table_id LIKE 'ga_sessions_%'
ORDER BY
  4 DESC
```

Result (on some random GA dataset I have access to FYI)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but here you know in advance which are the sharded tables and which is not. What if you want to know the size of every table and the size of the sharded tables summed? (not knowing in advance that there is ga_sessions_ and a ga_sessions_intraday, and also just normal tables besides that)

Comment: btw i really like your POW(1024, 3), much more understandable then my POW(2, 30) :))